# Some magic to remount /system

Tags: adb, boot-loop, superuser, stock-rom

First of all:
Phone's model is Alcatel One Touch Idol Mini / 6012X
Chipset model is MT6572

The short version:

The device is in boot loop and to resolve this I must rename a file. The problem is that the file is in /system and I haven't granted ADB superuser permissions (So ADB simply hangs on "su", even when running scripts through ADB. Also "at" is not installed). Another problem is that I haven't installed a custom recovery and, more importantly, I haven't even unlocked the boot loader.

I can't manage to install custom images via SP Flash Tool (SP Flash Tool doesn't find the device although the VCOM USB drivers are installed).

What's worse than this? Alcatel doesn't provide a way to reflash the stock ROM.

So, my question:
Is there some kind of magic to force "su" to execute through adb without adb being granted permission by SuperSU?

Comment: I doubt that. That would render the entire security system useless if it were possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2489551), your device is rootable using framaroot.

As you only need a temproot, the first thing to try would be to:

- extract the temproot binary used by framaroot and push it to `/data/local/tmp` or any folder where you can set permissions
- flag this file as executable then run it

  ```
  $ chmod 777 filename
  $ ./filename
  ```
- if successful, you have temp root and can remount the system read/write

  ```
  # mount -o remount,rw /system /system
  ```

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct (although I've managed to "update" the phone via the officially provided tool - thank god it doesn't check versions prior to updating)